# creating a thread safe decorator class

Tags: python, multithreading, decorator

I've written a class that I'm using as a decorator. What I've done clearly isn't thread safe, but needs to be.

Here's a very simple example:

```
class DecoratorClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'initing DecoratorClass'
        self.counter = 0

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):

        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            print '\nin wrapped func, func name:', func.func_name
            print 'count val:', self.counter
            self.counter += 1
            ret_val = func()
            return ret_val

        return wrapped_func

@DecoratorClass()
def decorated_with_class():
    return

decorated_with_class()
decorated_with_class()
decorated_with_class()
```

This is the output:

```
initing DecoratorClass

in wrapped func, func name: decorated_with_class
count val: 0

in wrapped func, func name: decorated_with_class
count val: 1

in wrapped func, func name: decorated_with_class
count val: 2
```

So I'm getting one instance of DecoratorClass, which is shared between the three functions that have been decorated with it. Is there a straightforward way to get a new DecoratorClass instance on each call of decorated_with_class()? Or some other way to make this thread safe (e.g. have self.counter begin at 0 each time)? Or is this a lost cause?

Edits for clarifiation:

- I've intentionally omitted any threading in this example for the sake of keeping things simple; the environment in which I'm working WILL be threaded, but this example is not.
- I'm not actually counting anything in my production code. My real issue is that I have an instance variable on my decorator class, which may be updated by two instances of the same function each running in different threads. I just used the counter example to show that the decorator class only gets one instance, which maintains state. I need each of the threads/functions to either 1. get their own instance of the decorator class or 2. wait until no other threads are using the decorator class.

Comment: If you need the state of the counter to be per-call, it shouldn't really be in the decorator object. Move the counter to something whose scope is the `__call__()` method?  Not sure how to be less vague here, since I'm not sure what you're trying to count if you want the counter to be different for every call.

Comment: Also, the `DecoratorClass` instance isn't shared between all functions that are decorated with it, just between all calls to a single function: https://ideone.com/2v4EAX. If threading is an issue here, it's not present in the code you've posted.

Comment: I added some comments to my original post for clarification, but just to reiterate here, I'm not actually counting anything in my "real" code and threading WILL be an issue, I just didn't include it in my post since I didn't want to make my question overly complicated.

Comment: Okay, but then I have no idea whatsoever what you're asking about, since it doesn't seem like your question and the code in it has all that much in common with your actual problem beyond "there's a decorator."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's a better example of what I was running into:

```
import threading
import time

class DecoratorClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = None

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            curr_thread = threading.currentThread().getName()
            self.thread = curr_thread
            print '\nthread name before running func:', self.thread
            ret_val = func()
            print '\nthread name after running func:', self.thread
            return ret_val

        return wrapped_func

@DecoratorClass()
def decorated_with_class():
    print 'running decorated w class'
    time.sleep(1)
    return

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=decorated_with_class)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

This outputs:

```
thread name before running func: Thread-1
running decorated w class

thread name before running func: Thread-2

thread name before running func: running decorated w classThread-3
thread name before running func:

running decorated w class

thread name before running func:Thread-5

running decorated w class
Thread-5
running decorated w class

thread name after running func: Thread-5

thread name after running func: Thread-5

thread name after running func: Thread-5

thread name after running func: Thread-5

thread name after running func: Thread-5
```

So, clearly all the threads are using the same instance of DecoratorClass, and self.thread ends up being Thread-5 by the time all of them are done running (rather than being the name of the thread that actually ran the code.)

I just needed to add a lock into my decorator, like so:

```
class DecoratorClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = None
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):

            self.lock.acquire()

            curr_thread = threading.currentThread().getName()
            self.thread = curr_thread

            print '\nthread name before running func:', self.thread
            ret_val = func()
            print '\nthread name after running func:', self.thread
            self.lock.release()
            return ret_val

        return wrapped_func

@DecoratorClass()
def decorated_with_class():
    print 'running decorated w class'
    time.sleep(1)
    return

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=decorated_with_class)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Now my output looks like this, which is what I want:

```
thread name before running func: Thread-1
running decorated w class

thread name after running func: Thread-1

thread name before running func: Thread-2
running decorated w class

thread name after running func: Thread-2

thread name before running func: Thread-3
running decorated w class

thread name after running func: Thread-3

thread name before running func: Thread-4
running decorated w class

thread name after running func: Thread-4

thread name before running func: Thread-5
running decorated w class

thread name after running func: Thread-5
```

Comment: You should use `with` for lock acquisition as in my answer.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the try/finally block should be the same as with, right? Both acquire the lock and then release it when exiting the block.

Comment: That should be at least very similar. But why bother when you can just use the `with` statement? That's the generally accepted way of acquiring locks, opening files, etc. It also means you don't need to know about what is going on in an object's `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.

Comment: what if I happen to be in a production environment where we need to support python 2.4? :) (I'm not, but that would be a reason to "bother")

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear (to me) why you need multiple instances of `DecoratorClass`, but what if instead you just added a `threading.Lock` to the wrapped function thread safe?

```
class DecoratorClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'initing DecoratorClass'
        self.counter = 0
        self._lock = Lock()

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            with self._lock:
                print '\nin wrapped func, func name:', func.func_name
                print 'count val:', self.counter
                self.counter += 1
                ret_val = func()
                return ret_val

        return wrapped_func
```

Comment: Why would you lock the creation of the `wrapped_func`? Unless the use case involved doing `ReusedDecorator = DecoratorClass()` then doing `@ReusedDecorator` on several functions, you'd never be invoking `__call__` more than once for a given instance of `DecoratorClass`. And even if you did it that way, you'd only risk thread issues if the decoration was for a dynamically produced function; if the decoration is done at import time, the import lock is already protecting the same module from being imported by different threads in parallel...

Comment: Thanks, that was meant to be inside the wrapped func, edited.

Comment: Basically, I've got a bunch of functions that do different things, but all need to do the SAME thing once they finish running. I had done this by adding the same decorator to each function. However, the same function may be called by multiple threads at once - in this case, the threads could overwrite data in the decorator's instance variables, since both calls to that same function will share the same decorator class instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in maintaining a copy of the counter for each function you decorate, you can store it in the function itself. Remember that functions are normal Python objects:

Replace `self.counter += 1` with

```
if hasattr(func, "counter"):
    func.counter += 1
else:
    func.counter = 0
```

Since your decorator class will no longer have state, you can replace it with just a function that implements `__call__`:

```
def DecoratorMethod(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        with func._lock:
            if not hasattr(func, "counter"):
                func.counter = 0
            print '\nin wrapped func, func name:', func.func_name
            print 'count val:', func.counter
            func.counter += 1
            ret_val = func()
            return ret_val

    return wrapped_func
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DecoratorClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'initing DecoratorClass'
        self.counter = 0

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):

        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            print '\nin wrapped func, func name:', func.func_name
            print 'count val:', self.counter
            self.counter += 1
            ret_val = func()
            return ret_val

        return wrapped_func

@DecoratorClass()
def decorated1():
    return

@DecoratorClass()
def decorated2():
    return

@DecoratorClass()
def decorated3():
    return

decorated1()
decorated2()
decorated3()
```

gets me

```
initing DecoratorClass
initing DecoratorClass
initing DecoratorClass

in wrapped func, func name: decorated1
count val: 0

in wrapped func, func name: decorated2
count val: 0

in wrapped func, func name: decorated3
count val: 0
```

Does this help?